# Convert a hstore into a Map object

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, hstore

I can't figure out to convert a string formatted like:

```
"'keyTest'=>'valueTest', 'keyTest2'=>'valueTest2',..."
```

to a Map object simply. I can do it with foreach but i wonder if there is a prettier way ?

I can do it like so :

```
let linksMap = new Map<string, string>();
family.links.split(',').forEach((element) => {
  const keyVal = element.split('=>');
  linksMap.set(keyVal[0], keyVal[1]);
});
```

Is there a way to cast directly or something like that ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to fix this at the source, so that you can work with a proper format (like JSON)?

Comment: Yeah, parsing strings like this is one of those red flags.  What happens if you ever have a key or value with a comma or a `=>` in it?  Then your splitting code will be messed up.  Do you have a clear definition of the format of the string along with escaping rules? Or is it just some ad-hoc encoding?  If it's the former, we can help write something. If it's the latter, all bets are off.

Comment: Actually I receive that from the db : '"Test key"=>"value", "Test key2"=>"value2"'

Comment: And is there some kind of specification for how that string is encoded?

Comment: I dont' know, it's like a map already but in a string or some kind of json ? but i can't parse it without an error

Comment: Then we can't tell you the best way to parse that thing.  Write whatever code you want to produce an array of entries and then you can call `new Map(entries)`, but the way you convert that string into an array of entries isn't specified anywhere.  You can try to just `split` it like you're doing, and then one day you get a comma in a value and everything implodes. For the purposes of this question, you should [edit] to give us some specification for how the string is encoded (e.g., "the only places `,` and `=>` appear is where they are delimiters), or there aren't enough details to answer.

Comment: ok thank you for your time, i will get more info on how is encoded the string

Comment: Ok the data is not a string but a hstore in a postgres db !

Comment: So then are you asking how to parse hstore into a JS object (in which case you should tag the question with "hstore") or are you asking how to turn a JS object into a Map (which has nothing to do with your particular parsing)?

Comment: ok my question is how to parse hstore into a Map in typescript using svelte

Comment: Solved ! I had to convert into the db request (postgres) adding in the Select : hstore_to_json ("Table"."Column") json

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map` constructor

```js
const string = "'keyTest'=>'valueTest', 'keyTest2'=>'valueTest2'"

const map = new Map(string.split(',').map(item => item.trim().split('=>')))

console.log([...map])
```